# Unable to retrieve embedded image from compiled ASP.NET assembly

Tags: asp.net, image, resources, assemblies

I have a simple project with a namespace of 'Search' which contains a number of images which have been marked as embedded resources.

I've entered this into Assembly.vb after checking the reference with Reflector to ensure the image is in the assembly. I've placed the image 'whole.gif' in the root of the application.

```
<Assembly: System.Web.UI.WebResource("Search.whole.gif", "image/gif")>
```

My code to render the image is below, it should by rights render the image but doesn't and I can't for the life of me see why.

```
Private Sub Page_PreRender(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRender
    btnImgAll.ImageUrl = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.GetType(), "Search.whole.gif")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem reference to the type which is almost every example given I could find uses Me.GetType(). I chased every other avenue aside from checking this argument until I can across a chance remark in a forum post.

I changed the line

```
btnImgAll.ImageUrl = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(Me.GetType(), "Search.whole.gif")
```

to

```
btnImgAll.ImageUrl = Page.ClientScript.GetWebResourceUrl(GetType(Content_Modules_RegionSelector), "Search.whole.gif")
```

where Content_Modules_RegionSelector is the class name of the parent control, which in my case is a simple web user control.